# too many values to unpack (expected 2) error while getting value of list from model

Tags: django-models, django-views

in my view.py i have following get method `delivered = Orders.filter('Delivered').count()` which supposed to return result but when i try to run it it shows error **too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

here are my codes

> Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *


def index(request):

    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    Orders = orders.objects.all()
    total_orders = Orders.count()
    total_customers= customers.count()
    delivered = Orders.filter('Delivered').count()
    pending= Orders.filter('Pending').count()

    context = {'customers': customers,
               'Orders': Orders,
               'total_orders': total_orders,
               'total_customers': total_customers,
               'delivered':delivered,
               'pending':pending
               }
    return render(request, 'website/index.html', context)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        phone= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        email= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class Products(models.Model):
        CATEGORY= (
            ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
            ('Out Door', 'Out Door')
        )
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        price= models.FloatField(null=True)
        category= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices= CATEGORY)
        discription = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class orders(models.Model):
        STATUS = (

            ('Pending', 'Pending' ),
            ('Out of Delivery ',' Out of Delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),

        )

        customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.product
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you had made a silly mistake

```
delivered = Orders.filter('Delivered').count()
pending= Orders.filter('Pending').count()
```

This will be something like this. You have to mention the database field name in your case it's status

```
delivered = Orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
pending= Orders.filter(status='Pending').count()
```